# Get attachment from mail using php

Tags: php, email, attachment

I need code to monitor my mail inbox and forward the mails with an attachment to another email address. I used the code below to fetch the attachments from the received messages. But I'm getting an error "Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$disposition in C:\wamp\www\mail\c.php on line 60"

Here is my code

```
<?php
 $host = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert/norsh}inbox';
 $login = 'AAAA@CCC.com';
 $password = 'XXXXXXX';
 $savedirpath = "../mail";
 $type = 'ReadAttachment';
$obj = new $type;
$obj->getdata($host,$login,$password,$savedirpath,$delete_emails=false);
class ReadAttachment{

function getdecodevalue($message,$coding) {
    switch($coding) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
            $message = imap_8bit($message);
            break;
        case 2:
            $message = imap_binary($message);
            break;
        case 3:
        case 5:
            $message=imap_base64($message);
            break;
        case 4:
            $message = imap_qprint($message);
            break;
    }
    return $message;
}

function getdata($host,$login,$password,$savedirpath,$delete_emails=false) {
    // make sure save path has trailing slash (/)
    //print_r("test");
    $savedirpath = str_replace('\\', '/', $savedirpath);
    if (substr($savedirpath, strlen($savedirpath) - 1) != '/') {
        $savedirpath .= '/';
    }

    $mbox = imap_open ($host, $login, $password) or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());
    $message = array();
    $message["attachment"]["type"][0] = "text";
    $message["attachment"]["type"][1] = "multipart";
    $message["attachment"]["type"][2] = "message";
    $message["attachment"]["type"][3] = "application";
    $message["attachment"]["type"][4] = "audio";
    $message["attachment"]["type"][5] = "image";
    $message["attachment"]["type"][6] = "video";
    $message["attachment"]["type"][7] = "other";
    //print_r($message);
    $emails = imap_search($mbox,'ALL');
    foreach($emails as $email_number) {
        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($mbox, $email_number , FT_UID);    
        $parts = $structure->parts;
        $fpos=2;
        for($i = 1; $i < count($parts); $i++) {
            $message["pid"][$i] = ($i);
            $part = $parts[$i];

            if($part->disposition == "ATTACHMENT") {
                $message["type"][$i] = $message["attachment"]["type"][$part->type] . "/" . strtolower($part->subtype);
                $message["subtype"][$i] = strtolower($part->subtype);
                $ext=$part->subtype;
                $params = $part->dparameters;
                $filename=$part->dparameters[0]->value;

                $mege="";
                $data="";
                $mege = imap_fetchbody($mbox,$email_number,$fpos);  
                $filename="$filename";
                $fp=fopen($savedirpath.$filename,"w");
                $data=$this->getdecodevalue($mege,$part->type);
                //print_r($data);
                fputs($fp,$data);
                fclose($fp);
                $fpos+=1;
            }
        }

    }
    // imap_expunge deletes all tagged messages

    imap_close($mbox);
}
}
```

Thanks to the author, but I couldn't get any help further.
I'm getting an error `"Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$disposition in C:\wamp\www\mail\c.php on line 60"`
This exactly point out the line `if($part->disposition == "ATTACHMENT")`.
Please provide me with a solution.

I am new to php, struggling to write this mail function,,

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Please post the complete error message and point out, what you have tried until now.

Comment: You will find a decent imap example here: http://www.linuxscope.net/articles/mailAttachmentsPHP.html

Comment: Yeah I tried it out. But even I am getting errors in it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if $disposition exists first:

if((isset($part->disposition))&&($part->disposition == "ATTACHMENT"))